# How to force SSL clients to go HTTP with htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

My previously website was using a SSL certificate and so then I forced https.
Now my new up-to-date website doesn't use SSL because it don`t need to, so the cached versions of my clients when using https breaks css and image links.

I am using *wordpress*, but I am trying to find a way to force redirect https loadings to http on the `.htaccess` file.

Anyone?

Comment: I dont understand why people downvoted my question. I have an issue because SSL is cached by browser so if people come along using https the website crashes because there are several links and images that aren`t working on https because of content-mixed policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Rough example of how you can do this right on the web server with .htaccess. However, this still means your web server needs to be able to answer an HTTPS request, which requires a valid certificate. The `301` redirect will disabuse clients of their cache, however it will take a while until all cached clients will have gone through this process, so you need to leave this up for a while.

Comment: I have try using it but the apache version of the server doesn't appear to respond to the HTTPS cond. I have a valid certificate but I don't want to use it. I have managed to solve my issue using php, anyway. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

So when a request comes in using HTTPS you to redirect it to HTTP - but you have no mechanism for processing the HTTPS request - so your server will never *see* the request in order to redirect it.

Comment: I do think so. I was trying to use this piece of code below:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

But apparently it works on only certain versions of apache

Comment: No HTTPS, No Request. Any webserver.

Comment: I think the browser caches the https forcing the client to come with https enabled

Comment: Is there any way to force HTTP when a user comes with https?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that with php, although can't do it via .htaccess

```
if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] == 443)
|| (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
|| (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'))  {
    header("Location:".get_bloginfo("url"));
    exit();
}
```